# If $a$ is an odd integer, then prove that $24\mid a(a^2 - 1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> If $a$ is an odd integer, then prove that $24\mid a(a^2 - 1)$

So, I simplified $a(a^2 -1)$ to $a(a+1)(a-1)$.

Now, I have seen some answers which first say that this is clearly divisible by $6$ and go on to express this as a multiple of $4$.

But such answers ignore that $2$ could be a common multiple. So that they ultimately prove $12\mid a(a^2 -1)$

Now, back to my unfinished proof.
I let $a = 2k+1$ and substituted this value of $a$ to get:
$4(2k+1)(k)(k+1)$

And here I am stuck...

Comment: Welcome to MSE! For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: 2 cannot be a common multiple of all three factors: if a is even, then a+1 and a-1 are odd.  If a is odd, then a+1 and a-1 are even.

Comment: Your point that they end up proving it is divisible by $12$ is not correct. If $a$ is odd both $a-1$ and $a+1$ are even and one of them is divisible by $4$. So their product is divisible by $8$. Also one of the $3$ numbers is divisible by $3$.

Comment: What can you say about $k(k+1)$? Note also (though you may need to prove it) that of two successive even integers, one is divisible by $4$ - or alternatively that the square of an odd number $\equiv 1 \bmod 8$

Comment: It's tedious, but one approach is to consider $a=6k+r$ for $r=0,1,2,3,4,5$.

Comment: An interesting way to so this is to note that the sum of the first $k$ squares (certainly an integer) is $\frac {k(k+1)(2k+1)}6$ - more work than you need to do, I think.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1427734/prove-that-24-mid-aa2-1)

Comment: In my opinion, simplest is to note that given 3 consecutive integers, one must be a multiple of 3, and given 2 consecutive even integers, one must be a multiple of 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now you just need to prove that $4(2k+1)(k)(k+1)$ is divisible by $24$.

Note that one of $k$ or $k+1$ is always even. Hence the expression is divisible by $8$.

Now, if either of $k$ or $k+1$ is divisible by $3$, you are done.

But if not, $k+2$ must be divisible by $3$ and so should be $k-1$, and hence so should $(k+2)+(k-1)=2k+1$. Hence it is divisible by $3$ as well.

Comment: Thank you, this does solve my doubt. But just out of curiosity, is there any way this can be proved completely mathematically?

Comment: This **is** completely mathimatically.

Comment: Okay, thank you!

Comment: If you think that taking cases is not completely mathematically, then can you show me how would you prove $k(k+1)$ is even for all integral $k$ completely mathematically?

Comment: That's exactly what I can't do! Perhaps something like expanding it to 2m + 1 or 2m and then doing it on with 3j +1, 3j + 2,...?

Comment: Taking cases is the only way it can be done, because we are in number theory, we need to use the fact that $k$ is an integer. That's how number theory works (unlike algebra)!

Answer (score 3):

If $a\equiv3\pmod4$ then $4|a+1$ and $2|a-1$, so $8|(a+1)(a-1)$.

If $a\equiv1\pmod4$ then $2|a+1$ and $4|a-1$, so $8|(a+1)(a-1)$.

Either way, $8|a(a+1)(a-1)$.

You should be able to see that at one of $a-1$, $a$, $a+1$ is divisible by $3$. Once you show that then you can conclude $24|a(a+1)(a-1)$.